# Rails AASM does not rollback when validation returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aasm

I have a model Booking that changes the status using AASM

**models/booking.rb**

```
before_validation :item_availability, if: -> { pending? || approved? }

enum status: [:pending, :approved, :rejected, :on_loan, :returned]

aasm column: :status, enum: true, whiny_transitions: true do
  state :pending, initial: true 
  state :approved

  event :approve do
    transitions from: :pending, to: :approved
  end
end

private
 def item_availability
    if quantity.to_f > item.quantity.to_f
      errors.add(:base, "Not enough quantity for #{item.name} only #{item.quantity} left")
      false
    end
  end
```

and I have a service that triggers the approve! event

```
  def run
    booking.transaction do
      booking.approve! 
      booking.item.decrement!(:quantity, booking.quantity)
      BookingsMailer.send_approval(booking).deliver_now
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    errors.add(:base, e.message)
    false
  end
```

The problem here is the validation is being hit because the quantity is greater than the booking's quantity but the transaction in my service does not rollback.

According to documentation

> Saving includes running all validations on the Job class. If
>   whiny_persistence flag is set to true, exception is raised in case of
>   failure.

I already set whiny_transitions to true but

Comment: Do you need to throw an exception along with adding errors?

Comment: @emaillenin the whiny_persitence flag of aasm doesn't do that?

Comment: I haven't used that gem before, I was just giving a alternate suggestion

Comment: I know this is a very late comment but in aasm 5.1 to raise an exception it needs a guard.